# How to use FHIR custom tags

Tags: hl7-fhir

For workflows I want to add [tags](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/resource-definitions.html#Meta.tag) to resources. For example

workflow1: state1, state2, state3, undefined

Questions:

1. do I have to define a own CodeSystem? If yes, how?
2. Do I need a ValueSet? And how to define?

Thank you for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a code system, but don't necessarily need to have a CodeSystem instance that exposes the codes.  (Though validators will spit out warnings that they can't check the codes if they can't find a CodeSystem for the specified Coding.system url.)  If you want to constrain the set of tags allowed, you'll need to define a ValueSet and bind to that ValueSet in your profile.